# How to prove greedy algorithm for number partitioning?

Tags: algorithm, greedy

> the [partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) (or number partitioning[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem)) is the task of
>   deciding whether a given multiset S of positive integers can be
>   partitioned into two subsets S1 and S2 such that the sum of the
>   numbers in S1 equals the sum of the numbers in S2.

There is a greedy algorithm for this problem:

> One approach to the problem, imitating the way children choose teams
>   for a game, is the greedy algorithm, which iterates through the
>   numbers in descending order, assigning each of them to whichever
>   subset has the smaller sum. This approach has a running time of O(n
>   log n). This heuristic works well in practice when the numbers in the
>   set are of about the same size as its cardinality or less, but it is
>   not guaranteed to produce the best possible partition. For example,
>   given the set S = {4, 5, 6, 7, 8} as input, this greedy algorithm
>   would partition S into subsets {4, 5, 8} and {6, 7}; however, S has an
>   exactly balanced partition into subsets {7, 8} and {4, 5, 6}.

But, I don't know how to prove `This heuristic works well in practice when the numbers in the set are of about the same size as its cardinality or less`. Can anyone help?

Comment: This might be a better fit for [cs.stackexchange.com](http://cs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Prove what? It's correctness? The quote above indicates that the greedy algorithm is imperfect.

Comment: Prove `This heuristic works well in practice when the numbers in the set are of about the same size as its cardinality or less`

Comment: Cross-posted: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39693921/781723, http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/63882/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 1):

The claim is not a precise one; it's just saying that if the elements of the multiset aren't **much** bigger than its cardinality, then the heuristic will **usually** give the right answer, unless you make a point of seeking out cases where it doesn't. So the claim can't really be "proven" as-is.

Furthermore, there are many different ways that the claim *could* be made precise; and not all of those ways necessarily result in a true claim. So you can't just make the claim precise and then prove that.

---

However, if you read the paragraph *after* the one you cite, it offers a related claim that *is* precise, and that is (according to the article) correct, namely that if the multiset *S* can be partitioned into two multisets whose sums are both ≤ *OPT*, then this greedy algorithm will partition it into two multisets whose sums are both ≤ ⁷/₆ *OPT*. However, this claim is not the same as the original claim; it sets an upper bound on how wrong the heuristic can be, but it doesn't guarantee that it's ever *exactly* right, and it doesn't make any reference to the values of the elements.